# Diseño de tabla con multiples datos

Tags: html

Tengo una `tabla` que va a almacenar muchos datos aproximadamente mas de 100, el problema es que mi `tabla` es bastante larga y para ver la información es necesario con un `scroll`. Pero el `scroll` que sale esta al final de la tabla y no se me hace muy estetico o practico que este allí, ya que si quiero mirar la informacion de una fila que esta en la mitad de la tabla es incomodo ir hasta abajo y mover.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recreo la tabla que tengo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Mas o menos así es mi tabla pero con mas encabezados entonces si te fijas si quiero ver la informacion de una fila de la mitad es muy incomodo movernos horizontalmente.

Como puedo hacerlo mas practico?

Comment: sino tiene muchos datos. podrías hacer los encabezados verticalmente, es decir los encabezados hacia abajo y a la derecha la información, echa un [vistazo](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_headers)

Comment: Podrías ver si te funciona [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css)

Comment: @Lucía No creo que funcione adecuadamente ya que como te digo el problema no es verticalmente ya que eso puede bajar con el mouse, el problema es horizontalmente para ver todos los datos que lleva dicha fila

Comment: @Charls El problema es que quieren la tabla con los encabezados horizontalmente

Comment: @Lucía Ingrese un "ejemplo" de como es mi tabla para que sea mas facil de ver

Comment: @Lucía No deja desplazarme si no llego abajo exacto, como podria diseñarla para que funcione de forma comoda

Comment: ¿Te serviría algo como [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520098/html-css-row-break-for-long-table-needs-a-fix)? También puedes aplicar `<div>` y modificar estos a tu antojo. En cualquier caso, el scroll horizontal no hace falta ir abajo a hacerlo "manualmente". Presionando la ruleta del ratón y desplazando hacia la dirección deseada es suficiente

Comment: @Lucía No me sirve de mucho el enlace pero gracias, y entiendo que para moverme horizontalmente lo puedo hacer así pero pienso que el aplicativo lo usara gente que a lo mejor no sepa eso entonces seria un problema

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurre poner un scrollbar encima de la tabla (manteniendo el que está debajo), esto con un div extra que simule el scrollbar superior y con eventos de Javascript para que capture el scroll en ambos casos.

```js
_ = x => document.getElementById(x);

_("content1").style.width = _("content2").clientWidth + "px";

_("wrapper1").addEventListener("scroll", e => _("wrapper2").scrollLeft = _("wrapper1").scrollLeft);
_("wrapper2").addEventListener("scroll", e => _("wrapper1").scrollLeft = _("wrapper2").scrollLeft);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}


#wrapper1 {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 20px;
}
#content1 {
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1" style="overflow-x:auto">
  <div id="content1"></div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper2" style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table id="content2">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
</div>
```

O simplemente hacer que tu tabla tenga un alto fijo que ocupe la pantalla sin desbordarla, así podrán usar ambos scrolls (vertical y horizontal), sin tener que desplazarse mucho.

Comment: +1 porque es una solución simple y efectiva. El único detalle es que el OP no indico que busca soluciones `Javascript`

Comment: @Marcos sí, por eso puse otra opción en texto al final, de hecho es la que uso en mis aplicaciones, hacer que la tabla no desborde la pantalla del usuario con una altura fija.

Answer (score 2):

ahi te edite el codigo de tu tabla para que puedas agregarle un scroll. Lo que hice fue agregarle unos estilos css que ahi te los dejo y a la etiqueta  una 'class' con los nombres de los estilos que agregamos, 'table-wrapper-scroll-y' y el otro es 'my-custom-scrollbar'. De esta manera en los estilos css puedes modificar el alto fijo de la tabla modificando la etiqueta 'height' que se ecneuntra dentro de '.my-custom-scrollbar'. Cualquier duda me consultas. Espero te sirva. Saludos.

```css
.my-custom-scrollbar {
                                            position: relative;
                                            height: 300px;
                                            overflow: auto;
                                        }
                                        .table-wrapper-scroll-y {
                                            display: block;
                                        }
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

En términos de usabilidad estas yendo en la dirección equivocada. Es muy común que los usuarios pidan *“ver todo”*, lo cual no necesariamente significa *“todo al mismo tiempo”*, dado que difícilmente pondrás atención a más de 5 columnas; cuando bien podrías tener varios conjuntos de pocas columnas, uno por *Caso de Uso*.

Para éstos casos la recomendación es implementar **Personalización de columnas**, donde incluso se pueda elegir de conjuntos predefinidos.

Otro vicio es hacer análisis visuales: *“ponme todo a ver qué encuentro”*, si bien el caso puede ser válido para que usuarios expertos hallen nuevos casos de error, correlación, inconsistencia, etc. muchas veces es mejor programar la lógica de búsqueda y crear filtros predefinidos.

En otras palabras, cualquier esfuerzo para apoyar el uso de 100 columnas es mejor invertirlo para mostrar menos columnas, ya sea en tiempo de análisis, diseño ó programación.